# Why using AVG() and ROUND() function in the below manner doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database relation fake_apps with prices of fake apps.Now I'm trying to calculate the rounded value of avg of all prices upto 2 decimal places.

I can't understand why this query doesn't work.

```
SELECT ROUND(SELECT AVG(prices) FROM fake_apps,2) AS round_val;
```

It gives a syntactical error as follows on MySQL 8.0.18:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two sets of parentheses, one for `ROUND()` and one for the subquery:

```
SELECT ROUND( (SELECT AVG(prices) FROM fake_apps), 2) AS round_val;
```

Specifically, subqueries in SQL require their own sets of parentheses.

Here are two alternative methods of writing the query.

Put the `ROUND()` *in* the subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT ROUND(AVG(prices), 2) FROM fake_apps) AS round_val;
```

Dispense with the subquery altogether:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(prices), 2) AS round_val
FROM fake_apps ;
```